# Executing this shell script gives command not found error

Tags: shell, unix, wget

I am new to shell scripting. I am trying to write a script that reads URLs from a text file line by line and then fetches them using `wget`. Also I need to parse the log file for error messages.

```
#!/bin/sh
# SCRIPT:  example.sh

#reading the url file line by line

DIR = /var/www/html/

# wget log file
LOGFILE = wget.log

# wget output file
FILE = dailyinfo.`date +"%Y%m%d"`

cd $DIR

FILENAME = url.txt
cat $FILENAME | while read LINE
do
    echo "$LINE"
    wget $LINE -O $FILE -o $LOGFILE
done
```

I have changed the permissions using `chmod +x example.sh`
but upon execution I get `command not found` error for `DIR`, `FILE` and `LOGFILE`.
How to correct it?
Also how to go about the parsing part?

Answer (score 7):

problem `#1`, when assigning variables you must use the syntax:

```
VARIABLE=value
```

i.e. no space between the `VARIABLE` the `=` and the new value.

otherwise, it tries to execute `VARIABLE` as a command, which triggers the `command not found` error.

```
#!/bin/sh
# SCRIPT:  example.sh

#reading the url file line by line

DIR=/var/www/html/

# wget log file
LOGFILE=wget.log

# wget output file
FILE=dailyinfo.`date +"%Y%m%d"`

cd $DIR

FILENAME=url.txt
cat $FILENAME | while read LINE
do
    echo "$LINE"
    wget $LINE -O $FILE -o $LOGFILE
done
```

will probably get past the command not found errors

Answer (score 2):

Petesh is of course correct, you need to put the `=` sign straight after your variable name.

For this particular case, I suggest you use `wget -i input-urls.txt -o logfile.txt`, and then grep the logfile for errors. wget's `-i` flag reads a list of URLs from a text file, and "wgets" each of them, saving you re-inventing the wheel.

If you want it in a shell script, use something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=/var/www/html/
# wget log file
LOGFILE=wget.log
# wget output file
FILE=dailyinfo.`date +"%Y%m%d"`

# just for debugging
cd $DIR
echo "wget-ing urls from $FILE and writing them to $FILE in $DIR. Saving logs to $LOGFILE"

wget -i $FILE -o $LOGFILE
grep -i 'failed' logfile.txt
```

Here's an example error from the logfile:

```
--2013-01-15 15:01:59--  http://foo/
Resolving foo... failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘foo’
```

It's also useful to check the return code of wget. `0` indicates success, and non-zero values indicate various failures. You can check them by accessing the shell variable `$?`.

So, incorporating that, here's a sample script:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -i input-urls.txt -o logfile.txt
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "All good!"
else
    # handle failure
    grep -i 'failed' logfile.txt
fi
```

The return codes of wget are listed on the man page (`man wget`, or use an online resource like [this one](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Exit-Status)) if you need more detail. I gave it a quick experiment, and it looks like wget returns a non-zero exit code even if just one of the URLs triggers a failure.

Comment: It would be nice if you elaborated a bit more. For example, telling how the log looks like and what command and what regex would possibly help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same error message with tcsh `: Command not found.`

Oddly enough it was caused by the line endings. The same exact script works find with LF endings, but fails with CRLF endings.